# UIColor pattern with UIImage for retina display

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicolor

I hope this is a quick fix.

I'm trying to repeat a UIImage as a background texture and of course I want to accomodate for Retina display.

I have a background image (22px wide and 640px tall) that I want to repeat on the x-axis (it is oriented to Landscape) but have it scaled down to 11pt wide and 320pt tall. I tried:

```
UIColor *c = [UIColor patternWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg@2x.png"]];
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:c];
```

and it does not scale down, though it does repeat.

Any suggestions to how I can scale it down?

Comment: You shouldn't be referencing the @2x when you call a retina image programatically. Leave the 2x on the filename, just do [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'll write this as an answer, but the main problem (for the scaling at least) is that the system does not know that it IS in fact a retina image. It needs to search for the filename without the @2x, and then if there is an @2x, it will know it is supposed to be a retina version and thus will be scaled down.

ie. just do

```
[UIColor patternWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg"]];
```